# React-Native Android import from node_modules directory does not working

Tags: android, maven, react-native, gradle, jcenter

We are using react-native 0.43.4 version and we forked it. 
It is downloading via npm install.

**package.json**

```
"react-native": "git+ssh://git@subdomain.domain.net/username/react-native#fix/xcode_9_3",
```

Our Android **project-level gradle file** has

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()

        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }

        google()
    }
}
```

It was working almost a year. Our android project was using react-native which is inside of node_modules directory. but today, gradle automatically downloaded react-native 0.55.3 from jcenter.

**This image shows us react-native downloaded from jcenter**

[image: This image shows us react-native downloaded from jcenter]

We tried this

```
repositories {
    jcenter {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
}
```

but it did not work.

Any ideas how to fix this problem ?

Comment: My Android project stopped working suddenly too.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19259) on their GitHub explains what went wrong

Comment: Thank you, We will try this but I am thinking on other module dependencies like react-native-facebooksdk, react-native-google-anakytics e.t.c. I hope this will force other modules versions too.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook apparently released an maven artifact from the 0.55.3 version to jcenter. I think this wasn't intended as they stopped doing this with the version 0.20.1.

Since most of us have `implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+` in our build.gradle file your local version will be ignored and the highest version from jcenter will be used. The `+` is responsible for that as it takes the latest version available.

How to fix it:

1. delete your local gradle cache (and CI-server cache if you have one)
2. place your local maven above the jcenter in your build.gradle (local lookup over remote lookup)
3. to be sure: use `compile("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.43.4") { force = true }`

Answer (score 0):

`compile("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.43.4") { force = true }` in `android/app/build.gradle` also not woking agains https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210 , only below in `android/build.gradle` working:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        exclusiveContent {
            filter {
                includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
            forRepository {
                maven {
                    url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
    // actually now can remove below lines
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
    }
}
```

ref to https://github.com/flyskywhy/g/blob/master/i%E4%B8%BB%E8%A7%82%E7%9A%84%E4%BD%93%E9%AA%8C%E6%96%B9%E5%BC%8F/t%E5%BF%AB%E4%B9%90%E7%9A%84%E4%BD%93%E9%AA%8C/%E7%94%B5%E4%BF%A1/Tool/%E7%BC%96%E7%A8%8B%E8%AF%AD%E8%A8%80/JavaScript/React%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E8%AF%A6%E8%A7%A3.md#rootdirnode_modulesreact-nativeandroid-as-react-native-android-import-from-node_modules-directory-does-not-working